# unable to use derived string class with ifstream class

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I have a `UtlString` class which is derived from `std::string` and added extra utilities like to convert   int to string. But I am    getting some error when I used this class with stream in below code

```
istream& operator >> (istream& stream, UtlDatePeriod& object)
{

  stream >> (object._startDate).AsString() >> (object._endDate).AsString();
//(object._startDate).AsString() returns UtlString by value.
  return stream;


}
```

The error is:

```
error: no match for âoperator>>â in âstream >> std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(((const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)((const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*)(& jda::UtlDate::AsString() const().jda::UtlString::<anonymous>))))â

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/istream:119: note: candidates are: 
std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& (*)(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/istream:123: note:                 std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>& (*)(std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/istream:130: note:                 std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/istream:166: note:                 std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(bool&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/istream:170: note:                 std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(short int&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/istream:173: note:                 std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(short unsigned int&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/istream:177: note:                 std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(int&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/istream:180: note:                 std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(unsigned int&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/istream:184: note:                 std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(long int&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/istream:188: note:                 std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(long unsigned int&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/istream:193: note:                 std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(long long int&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/istream:197: note:                 std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(long long unsigned int&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/istream:202: note:                 std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(float&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/istream:206: note:                 std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(double&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/istream:210: note:                 std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(long double&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/istream:214: note:                 std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(void*&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/istream:238: note:                 std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]

    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2485: note:                 std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]
```

Comment: Deriving from `std::string` is bad mojo.  I think using composition rather than inheritance would make your problem much easier to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use inheritance to add extra utilities. Instead, add non-member functions to provide that functionality to a `std::string`. So instead of

```
class FancyString: public std::string
{
public:
     void doCoolStuff() const;
};
```

write

```
void doCoolStuff(std::string const& s);
```

If you (also) need to add extra state to a `std::string`, use composition

```
class FancyString
{
public: 
     void doCoolStuff() const;
private:
     int some_state;
     std::string s_;
};
```

`std::string` was never designed to be a base class. For one, it doesn't have a virtual destructor.

Comment: changes will be huge and cascading impact is enormous.

Comment: Good advice perhaps, but not an answer to the question.

Comment: @anonymous the error messages with bad class design will be huge and cascading and enormous.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is:

```
stream >> (object._startDate).AsString() ...
```

To clarify your problem, see below wrong code:

```
string f()
{
   return "Hi";
}

...

cin >> f(); // <--- ERROR
```

The object `cin` expects a non-const reference to a lvalue `string` but there is no such a thing.

Comment: but UtlString is derived class of std::string class so shouldn't it be substitutable for std::string?

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to read your new class from an istream you should add function

```
istream & operator >> (istream & is, Uistream&  data);
```